# Alert if a variable is is undefined

Tags: javascript

Following function gets a value `sp_value` from radio button if checked.

```
function spk() {
    if (document.getElementById('sp1').checked) {
        sp_value = document.getElementById('sp1').value;
    } else if (document.getElementById('sp2').checked) {
        sp_value = document.getElementById('sp2').value;
    } else if (document.getElementById('sp3').checked) {
        sp_value = document.getElementById('sp3').value;
    }
}
```

And put the value `sp_value` in audio source of following function

```
function PlayVerse(surat, n) {
    var aud = document.getElementById("myaudio");
    aud.src = "http://data.quranacademy.com/AUDIOS/VerseByVerse/Media-" +
        sp_value + "/01_" + TxtFormat(surat, "000") + "_" + TxtFormat(n, "000") + ".mp3";

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style = 'display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 4px; padding: 5px;';
    }
}
```

Now I want to alert a message when user click on function `PlayVerse` if the radio button is unchecked or you can say the `sp_Value` is undefined.

Comment: if (typeof sp_Value === "undefined") {...}

Comment: Or equivalently, more concisely, just `if (sp_Value === undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check if **sp_value** is **not empty** when calling PlayVerse():

```
if(sp_value) {
    PlayVerse(surat, n);
} else {
    alert("Please, select a value");
}
```

I hope that helps :-D

Comment: Will you please explain bit more that in which function I need to type above said script or I should type it separately??

Comment: You should use the code above whenever you would like to call PlayVerse(surat, n);. In other words, you should replace PlayVerse(surat, n); with :

Comment: if(sp_value) {
    PlayVerse(surat, n);
} else {
    alert("Please, select a value");
}

Comment: If that didn't make sense to you, please, attach to whole JS file to edit it for you :-D